# A C stack with minimum and maximum values

Tags: c, stack, statistics

I have this C stack implementation that knows its minimum and maximum values:

**minmax_stack.h**

```
#ifndef NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_MINMAX_STACK
#define NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_MINMAX_STACK

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct minmax_stack_node {
    void* datum;
    struct minmax_stack_node* next_node;
    struct minmax_stack_node* min_node;
    struct minmax_stack_node* max_node;
} minmax_stack_node;

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    minmax_stack_node* top_node;
    minmax_stack_node* min_node;
    minmax_stack_node* max_node;
    int (*compare)(void*, void*);
} minmax_stack;

void   minmax_stack_init (minmax_stack* stack, int (*compare)(void*, void*));
void   minmax_stack_free (minmax_stack* stack);
void   minmax_stack_push (minmax_stack* stack, void* datum);
size_t minmax_stack_size (minmax_stack* stack);
void*  minmax_stack_pop  (minmax_stack* stack);
void*  minmax_stack_min  (minmax_stack* stack);
void*  minmax_stack_max  (minmax_stack* stack);
void   minmax_stack_print(minmax_stack* stack);

#endif /* NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_MINMAX_STACK */
```

**minmax_stack.c**

```
#include "minmax_stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void minmax_stack_init(minmax_stack* stack, int (*compare)(void*, void*))
{
    stack->compare = compare;
    stack->size = 0;
    stack->top_node = NULL;
    stack->min_node = NULL;
    stack->max_node = NULL;
}

void minmax_stack_free(minmax_stack* stack)
{
    minmax_stack_node* current_node = stack->top_node;
    minmax_stack_node* next_node;

    while (current_node)
    {
        next_node = current_node->next_node;
        free(current_node);
        current_node = next_node;
    }

    stack->compare  = NULL;
    stack->min_node = NULL;
    stack->max_node = NULL;
    stack->top_node = NULL;
    stack->size     = 0;
}

void minmax_stack_push(minmax_stack* stack, void* datum)
{
    int cmp_min;
    int cmp_max;

    minmax_stack_node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->datum = datum;

    if (stack->top_node)
    {
        new_node->next_node = stack->top_node;
        new_node->min_node  = stack->min_node;
        new_node->max_node  = stack->max_node;
        stack->top_node     = new_node;

        cmp_min = stack->compare(datum, stack->min_node->datum);
        cmp_max = stack->compare(datum, stack->max_node->datum);

        if (cmp_min < 0) stack->min_node = new_node;
        if (cmp_max > 0) stack->max_node = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        stack->top_node = new_node;
        stack->min_node = new_node;
        stack->max_node = new_node;
        new_node->next_node = NULL;
    }

    stack->size++;
}

size_t minmax_stack_size(minmax_stack* stack)
{
    return stack->size;
}


void* minmax_stack_pop(minmax_stack* stack)
{
    minmax_stack_node* node;
    void* return_value;

    if (stack->size == 0) return NULL;

    node = stack->top_node;
    return_value = node->datum;
    stack->max_node = node->max_node;
    stack->min_node = node->min_node;
    stack->top_node = node->next_node;
    stack->size--;
    return return_value;
}

void* minmax_stack_min(minmax_stack* stack)
{
    return stack->size == 0 ? NULL : stack->min_node->datum;
}

void* minmax_stack_max(minmax_stack* stack)
{
    return stack->size == 0 ? NULL : stack->max_node->datum;
}

void minmax_stack_print(minmax_stack* stack)
{
    const char* separator = "";
    printf("[");

    for (minmax_stack_node* current_node = stack->top_node;
         current_node;
         current_node = current_node->next_node)
    {
        printf("%s", separator);
        printf("%d", (int) current_node->datum);
        separator = ", ";
    }

    printf("]");
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "minmax_stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int compare(void* a, void* b)
{
    return (int)((int) a - (int) b);
}

int main() {
    int num;
    minmax_stack stack;
    minmax_stack_init(&stack, compare);
    char command[100];

    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%s", command);

        if (strcmp(command, "push") == 0)
        {
            scanf("%d", &num);
            minmax_stack_push(&stack, (void*) num);
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "pop") == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", (int) minmax_stack_pop(&stack));
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "min") == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", (int) minmax_stack_min(&stack));
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "max") == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", (int) minmax_stack_max(&stack));
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "print") == 0)
        {
            minmax_stack_print(&stack);
            puts("");
        } else if (strcmp(command, "quit") == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Any critique is much appreciated.

Comment: What if I enter a really long command? More than 100 bytes?

Comment: @RolandIllig Why would you want to do something as stupid as that?

Comment: Just to crash your program. You know, I'm evil and I'm only waiting for you to write a web server or a setuid executable.

Comment: @RolandIllig Evil? You look more like Dorothy to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Leak**

When a node is popped, the node is not free'd.

**compare()**

Avoid `int` overflow which is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Use the idiom `(a>b)-(a<b)`.  It is recognized by a number of compilers to make lean code and does not overflow.

```
static int compare(void* a, void* b) {
    // return (int)((int) a - (int) b);
    return ((int) a > (int) b) - ((int) a < (int) b);
}
```

Note that `qsort()` expects `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)` and so follow that `const` signature. Adjust `minmax_stack` and functions accordingly.

Casting a `void *` to `int` may lose information.  If conversion to an integer type is truly needed, consider the optional type `intptr_t` or better yet `uintptr_t`.

> the property that any valid
>   pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer  C11dr §7.20.1.4 1

```
static int compare(const void* a, const void* b) {
    uintptr_t ua = (uintptr_t) a;
    uintptr_t ub = (uintptr_t) b;
    return (ua > ub) - (ua < ub);
}
```

**Printing `datum`**

Down casting to `int` can lose information.  As a `minmax_stack` function, better to show all information.

```
// printf("%d", (int) current_node->datum);
printf("%p", current_node->datum);
// or cast to widest type through `uintptr_t`
printf("%ju", (uintmax_t) (uintptr_t) current_node->datum);
```

**Prevent buffer overrun**

Although only test code, limit user input.

```
char command[100];
...
    // scanf("%s", command);
    scanf("%99s", command);
```

**Tolerate `stack == NULL`?**

Should functions tolerate `stack == NULL` - IMO yes, but a design decision.

`free(void *ptr)` is tolerant of `free(NULL)`, suggest the same for `minmax_stack_free()`.

```
void minmax_stack_free(minmax_stack* stack) {
  if (stack == NULL) return;
  ...
```

**Alloc size**

Good use of sizing by the referenced type, rather than the size of the explicit type!  Could add allocation success test.

```
//                                   size of referenced type 
minmax_stack_node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
if (new_node == NULL) TBD_Handle_Error();
```

Minor style implication: `sizeof(*new_node)` --> `sizeof *new_node`.

**Variable declaration**

A style issue, yet I find declaring variables when there are needed better as well as bracketed `if()`

```
// minmax_stack_node* node;
// void* return_value;
// if (stack->size == 0) return NULL;

if (stack->size == 0) { 
  return NULL;
}
minmax_stack_node* node = stack->top_node;
void* return_value = node->datum;
```

**Use of `NULL` as `datum`**

Code uses return value of `NULL` to indicate an error, yet a `datum == NULL` is not necessarily wrong in a general sense and so with a return value of `NULL`, it is ambiguous if that is an error or `datum`?  To support `datum == NULL`, the architecture of this code may need significant re-write.  Is this important? - Depends on coding goals.  For a general purpose function set, I say yes.

Comment: So maybe i'm missing something c - related (i'm coming from c++) but it looks like the compare here and the compare of the OP compares the incoming pointers and not the contents of the address pointed to. Should it not be `return (*ua > *ub) - (*ua < *ub);` ?

Comment: @HaraldScheirich Certainly OP's `compare()`function is only a _sample_ function used to exercise the `minmax_stack.c` code.  It could be quite different depending on the nature of the pushed/popped `void*`.  What is important here is its signature which I suggest to be `int compare(const void* a, const void* b)`, thus like compare functions for `qsort()`.

Comment: I hadn't seen the `(a>b)-(a<b)` idiom before - thanks for recommending that!